# How do you pass an io-file-like StringIO object to a subprocess that expects a specific file as input

Tags: python, subprocess, stringio, lilypond

I am trying to pass a file-like StringIO object to a subprocess which expects a file "file.ly". Possible problems might be the file extension and expected apostrophes before and after the filename.

I tried:

```py
import subprocess
import lilypond
from io import StringIO  

string ='{e c}'
file = StringIO(string)
print(file.read())
file.seek(0)

subprocess.run([lilypond.executable(),"-fpng", file.read()])
```

The code works as expected when using:

```py
subprocess.run([lilypond.executable(),"-fpng", "file.ly"])
```

```
("file.ly" contains "{e c}")
```

Here is the error message:

```
{e c} Warnung: Datei »{e c}« kann nicht gefunden werden schwerer Fehler: gescheiterte Dateien: "{e c}"
```

This translates to the following (using google translate):

```
{e c} Warning: Cannot find file »{e c}« fatal error: failed files: "{e c}"
```

I suppose that this means that the python code is OK, but the lilypond subprocess doesn't like the input.

Is there a fix for this problem?

Comment: What exactly is `("file.ly" contains "{e c}")`? I've placed into a code block in my edit, could you add some explanation to it?

Comment: "_The error message is something like "can't find file"_" - Could you add the full error message, starting from the word `Traceback`? Even if it is German, it still gives us usefull information. A literal translation, possibly using machine translators, might also be usefull.

Comment: The file "file.ly" is a text file with the the extension ".ly". It contains the text "{e c}". lilypond converts the text to a png with a musical notations.

Comment: Do you know what the call to lilypond would look like if you just did it on the command line instead of from your Python script?  Here it seems like the call that doesn't work is asking lilypond to open a file called `{e c}` which indeed is very unlikely to exist. If this tool expects a filename as its argument, you have to pass the name of a file that actually exists on disk.